# Drawing bezier curve in Java

Tags: java, swing, bezier

I need to create a simple Java program, that draws a bezier curve pixel by pixel through any amount of points. At the moment, everything seems to be ok except that the curve always ends at x=0 y=0 coordinates.

Screenshot 1

[image]

Screenshot 2

[image]

I need it to end at the last point. My brain is not quite working today, so I'm looking for some help.

Here is what I have:

```java
private void drawScene(){

    precision = Float.parseFloat(this.jTextField4.getText());
    //Clears the screen and draws X and Y lines
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, pWidth, pHeight);

    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.drawLine(0, offsetY, pWidth, offsetY);
    g.drawLine(offsetX, 0, offsetX, pHeight);
    //Drawing the points
    if(pointCount > 0){
        for(int i = 0;i<pointCount;i++){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(i+1), points[i].x + offsetX, points[i].y - 6 + offsetY);
            g.drawOval(points[i].x + offsetX, points[i].y - 6 + offsetY, 3, 3);
        }
    }
    //Drawing the curve
    if(pointCount > 1){
        float t = 0;
        while(t <= 1){
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            this.besierCurvePixel(t);
            t += precision;
        }
    }
}

//Factorial
private static int fact(int n) {
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}
//Bernstein polynomial
private static double bernstein(float t, int n, int i){

   return (fact(n) / (fact(i) * fact(n-i))) * Math.pow(1-t, n-i) * Math.pow(t, i);
}

private void besierCurvePixel(float t){

    double bPoly[] = new double[pointCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++){
        bPoly[i] = bernstein(t, pointCount, i+1);
    }

    double sumX = 0;
    double sumY = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < pointCount;  i++){
        sumX += bPoly[i] * points[i].x;
        sumY += bPoly[i] * points[i].y;
    }

    int x, y;
    x = (int) Math.round(sumX);
    y = (int) Math.round(sumY);

    g.drawLine(x + offsetX, y + offsetY, x + offsetX, y + offsetY);

}
```

This is the method for adding the points (pointCount is 0 initially):

```
    points[pointCount] = new Point();
    points[pointCount].x = evt.getX() - this.offsetX;
    points[pointCount].y = evt.getY() - this.offsetY;
    pointCount++;

    this.drawScene();
```

Comment: What happens if you change `Math.pow(1-t, n-i)` in Bernstein method to: `Math.pow(1-t, n+1-i)`?

Comment: @Rekin [This happens](https://i.gyazo.com/a859b04c7494fec943f721eafecdd548.png)

Comment: I have troubles translating you factorial's method edge values to the ones in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: And what happens if instead of `for(int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++){ bPoly[i] = bernstein(t, pointCount, i+1);` you put `for(int i = 0; i <= pointCount; i++){ bPoly[i] = bernstein(t, pointCount, i);` ?

Comment: @Rekin I removed the binomial coefficient completely to see what happens and it still starts from 0. [Like so](https://i.gyazo.com/7c40e39646e25928930e7acfbd6e6050.png) But I do believe it's something to do with the bernstein polynomials. Either I've made a mistake in the formula or I'm using it wrong.

Comment: There must be some error with regards to bounds... If the whole equation goes to zero, it's either because of the nominator going to zero or denominator to infinity

Comment: @Rekin That example didn't work (array out of bounds), but you're right - the problem is there. When I added `if(pointCount == 4){
            bPoly[3] = bernstein(t, pointCount, pointCount);
        }` and added 4 points, everything worked!

Comment: A word of warning about using the factorial function: computing the binomial terms with "real maths" goes wrong really quickly, becaue the numbers get too big. Building the Pascal Triangle values directly, on the other hand, is much faster/cheaper and quite easily computed to almost abitrary depth. http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#explanation, "how to implement" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here

```
for(int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++){
    bPoly[i] = bernstein(t, pointCount, i+1);
}
```

The second parameter in the bernstein method was incorrect. Basically If I have 3 points, it should be 2 not 3;

```
bPoly[i] = bernstein(t, pointCount-1, i+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does "pointcount" get set (and to what)?
Have you tried stepping through your code to see why it continues after reaching the last point?
Is it possible that you are stepping through a loop 1 extra time, which is why the last point would have a destination set to (0,0)?
Could you set the number of steps for the app to make to each point?

Hopefully I am bringing up points to help you find your answer

*Edit: If I had to guess- you are accidentally adding an additional point of (0,0) to points[]; Here is where I am seeing it go to (0,0) after the last point:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pointCount;  i++){
    sumX += bPoly[i] * **points[i]**.x;
    sumY += bPoly[i] * **points[i]**.y;
}
```

Edit: Glad you were able to fix it, and hopefully i helped with finding that issue. Best of luck in the future!

Comment: I checked the points object with System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points)); and didn't seem to have any extra points;